# When do I have to check for integer overflow?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I have been researching about integer overflowing, and I ended creating a function that checks for integer overflows and underflows:

```
#include <exception>
#include <limits>

int safe_add(int a, int b) {
    if (a > 0 && b > INT_MAX - a) {
        throw std::exception("Integer overflow");
    } else if (a < 0 && b < INT_MIN - a) {
        throw std::exception("Integer underflow");
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

I was afraid of the possible performance issues, so I did the next benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

int safe_add(int a, int b) {
    if (a > 0 && b > INT_MAX - a) {
        throw std::exception("Integer overflow");
    } else if (a < 0 && b < INT_MIN - a) {
        throw std::exception("Integer underflow");
    }
    return a + b;
}

void bench_add() {
    for (int i = INT16_MIN; i < INT16_MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = INT16_MIN; j < INT16_MAX; j++) {
            volatile int x = i + j; //I make it volatile so the compiler doesn't optimize it out
        }
    }
}

void bench_safe_add() {
    for (int i = INT16_MIN; i < INT16_MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = INT16_MIN; j < INT16_MAX; j++) {
            volatile int x = safe_add(i, j); //I make it volatile so the compiler doesn't optimize it out
        }
    }
}

void bench_safe_add_with_try() {
    try {
        for (int i = INT16_MIN; i < INT16_MAX; i++) {
            for (int j = INT16_MIN; j < INT16_MAX; j++) {
                volatile int x = safe_add(i, j); //I make it volatile so the compiler doesn't optimize it out
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void chrono(const std::string& name, void function(void)) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    milliseconds start = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    function();
    long long time = (duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()) - start).count();
    std::cout << name << ": " << time << "ms" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    chrono("Standard add", bench_add);
    chrono("Safe add", bench_safe_add);
    chrono("Safe add surrounded by try block", bench_safe_add_with_try);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

In my machine (i7-6700K@4GHZ 16gb RAM) produces this output:

```
Standard add: 1341ms
Safe add: 13667ms
Safe add surrounded by try block: 13544ms
```

If I call first the function with the try block then the safe add time descends a lot. Maybe for branch prediction?

The point is that it seems that safe_add is much slower than simply adding, so when should I check for integer overflows? or when should I **NOT** check for integer overflows? Is it important to use it with every user input or should the program just crash? And when leading databases where the performance impact is much bigger because it needs another query?

Thank you, Pedro.

Comment: The program is not guaranteed to crash on integer overflow. It has undefined behaviour, which is to say it might do anything and nothing. If you know for sure that an operation cannot overflow, then don't check for overflow; you might for example have bounded values. If you cannot know for sure, you have to check.

Comment: @Krythic Sorry if I used wrong the word research, I am not a native English speaker

Comment: @IljaEverilä At least in VC++, an exception is thrown when there is an integer overflow.

Comment: You never need to check for integer overflow. Validate user input against some sanity real-world checks, use long long type if you expect big integers, use special class for very big integers of whatever size if you really need that (usually not). program will not crash because of integer overflow.

Comment: @Amadeus I have searched a lot and seen other stack overflow answers, but all were about how to check for integer overflow, I haven't found any question about when to check for it.

Comment: For your benchmark, did you enable optimization? Results (and answers) may change tremendously with optimization.

Comment: To compare the in the same situation you should create an add function, because bench_safe_add calls another function and bench_add doesn't. You also have to be careful with the compiler optimization.
In C# exception throw is very slow, I don't know in C++. You can create a function without exception throw to compare.

Comment: safe_add has 4 possible branchs and 3 arithmetic expressions , while `+`, is a single arithmetic expressions. What did you expect?

Comment: This seems relevant: [How Should You Write a Fast Integer Overflow Check?](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1139)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have already checked that, but thanks anyway

Comment: @PedroPalacios, to distinguish between checking and non-checking code, as your checking code *is embedded in a function call* (with its overhead) you should embed the normal add code you have written as `volatile int x = i + j;` in a function call also, to see the actual difference of adding one way against the other.  You have not taken into account the cost of a function call (you could have `inline`d the function, but this is a hint to the compiler, and you are not warranted to be obeyed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nikitoz has given the answer I wanted:

> You never need to check for integer overflow. Validate user input
>   against some sanity real-world checks, use long long type if you
>   expect big integers, use special class for very big integers of
>   whatever size if you really need that (usually not). program will not
>   crash because of integer overflow.

So I'll mark this as answered